# "LastBackupTime" importance for SQL Backups

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have been building an application to Backup SQL Databases using VDI using SMO.
I have a doubt whether i should be capturing the last backup time of a database along with the LSN or simply, just capture the LSN.

More precisely, i wanted to take Last Backup Time to know that if end-user is using another software to backup their SQL DB's using Copy-only method since copy-only method doesn't update LSN or truncate anything but does update the Last backup time.

So, if i am ignoring the last backup time information of any DB and simply capturing the LSN, is it going to cause any problems for me? in terms of recovery/backup if there are other 3rd party softwares into play?

:::: Edit :::::
I am a backup application developer and i would like to know, should i be capturing the Last Backup time of the database that my end-user would like to backup ? or just simply capture the LSN to maintain the Log chain?

Comment: do you have made some test and what are the wrong or missing info with the result ?

Comment: I have tested the backups by not capturing the lastbackuptime and so far i don't see any issues, but need experts comment as to what's the importance of capturing this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing your backup software for the purposes of ensuring recoverability (that is you're not taking copy-only backups yourself), don't worry about any copy-only backups that have been taken by others. As you've said, copy-only backups don't affect the backup chain.

The only thing that would mess you up is if someone else is taking a non-copy-only backup interleaved with yours. In that case, you could get into a situation where one of their backups relies on one of yours (or vice versa) and the restore scenario is complicated at a point where it really shouldn't be (i.e. the database is down and you need to recover it).

Comment: Agree and thanks for the explanation. So i guess, capturing LSN only should be fine...correct ?

Comment: I would think so. Since you're writing software that, if it doesn't work, could cause serious problems, make sure you test though!